# wget: Cannot connect to https website (TLS error)

Tags: https, cygwin, ssl-certificate, wget, ssl

I am trying to use `wget` via Cygwin to fetch some content from a https website. Unfortunately when I try to connect I get the following error:

```
#wget https://www.mysite.com/mycontent
Connecting to XXXXXXXX... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

The certificate is a VeriSign Class 3 and is not expired. I have tried using options `--no-check-certificate`, `--secure-protocol=SSLv2`, `--secure-protocol=SSLv3`, etc which doesn't work but gives a slightly different error:

```
$ wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 --no-check-certificate https://www.mysite.com/mycontent
Connecting to XXXXXX... connected.
GnuTLS: GnuTLS internal error.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I also tried exporting the DER certificate from Internet Explorer on my PC and then passing that certificate to wget which also failed:

```
$ wget --certificate-type=DER --certificate=mysite.cer https://www.mysite.com/mycontent
Connecting to XXXXX... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Is there something I'm missing? Can anyone point me in the direction of what I have to do to make this work?

Sorry but I had to redact the real server info for employer confidentiality reasons.

Here is my wget/cygwin configuration information:

```
$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on cygwin.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls -ntlm +opie +ssl/gnutls

Wgetrc:
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale
Compile: gcc-4 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc"
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I.
    -I/usr/src/wget-1.13.4-1/src/wget-1.13.4/src -I../lib
    -I/usr/src/wget-1.13.4-1/src/wget-1.13.4/lib -g -O2 -pipe
Link: gcc-4 -g -O2 -pipe -liconv -lintl /usr/lib/libgnutls.dll.a
    /usr/lib/libtasn1.dll.a /usr/lib/libz.dll.a
    /usr/lib/libgcrypt.dll.a /usr/lib/libgpg-error.dll.a
    /usr/lib/libintl.dll.a -L/usr/lib/ncursesw /usr/lib/libiconv.dll.a
    -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lz -lidn ftp-opie.o gnutls.o ../lib/libgnu.a
```

[image: Certificate Info]

Comment: If it helps the web server is an Oracle Application Server `Oracle-Application-Server-10g OracleAS-Web-Cache-10g/10.1.2.0.2`

Comment: I just tried this from a Linux box and it worked fine. So the problem seems to be specific to either Cygwin or the version of wget included with it.

Comment: ever get a solution to this?   I get this error with the latest cygwin wget/gnutls.  And it works ok for my on linux, as well.

Comment: No sorry I think I ended up using an alternate solution but I don't remember the details now.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when trying to `wget` something from an IIS box. There's an IIS bug that incorrectly processes SSL requests. Browsers ignore it, wget doesn't.

If I recall correctly (it's been years), there's a wget setting that tells it to ignore SSL cert errors... Maybe it's the `--sslcheckcert` option. Try using `--sslcheckcert=0`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't see any flag similar to that. Do you mean `--no-check-certificate`? I tried that as described above - didn't work.

Comment: No, that's a wget parameter, at least on my version. 1.9.1 on my Mac.

Comment: Does it only happen on that one site or can you, for instance, grab https://www.google.com ?

Comment: Ah. You're using a much older version of wget unfortunately. I'm using 1.13.4. No I can't grab google.com either - same error.

Comment: one should have also the wget built with ssl support on cygwin :
man wget |grep -i ssl
   HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options
       To support encrypted HTTP (HTTPS) downloads, Wget must be compiled with an external SSL library, currently
       OpenSSL.  If Wget is compiled without SSL support, none of these options are available.